# Explanation concerning a proof in probability

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

In a proof concerning Markov chains:

The sequence $(X_n)_{0 \leq n \leq N}$ has values in the space of states { 0,1}.

\begin{eqnarray}
P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} | X_n = i_n, \dots , x_0 = i_0) =& \frac{P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} \cap X_n = i_n, \dots , x_0 = i_0)}{P (X_n = i_n, \dots , x_0 = i_0)}\\
=& \frac{P(|X_{n+1}-X_n| = |i_{n+1} -i_n| \cap X_n = i_n, \dots , x_0 = i_0)}{P (X_n = i_n, \dots , x_0 = i_0)}\\
=& P(|X_{n+1}-X_n| = |i_{n+1} -i_n|)
\end{eqnarray}

Could anyone please explain how we moved from the first inequality to the second one? Based on which probability role we can say $$ P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} \cap X_n = i_n, \dots , x_0 = i_0) = P(|X_{n+1}-X_n| = |i_{n+1} -i_n| \cap X_n = i_n, \dots , x_0 = i_0)$$

Answer (score 1):

As your space of states is $\{0,1\}$, you know $X_{n+1}$ by knowing $X_n$ and $|X_{n+1}-X_n|$.

UPDATE:

The values of $X_{n+1}$ and $X_n$ set four different possibilities:

**if $(X_{n+1},X_n)=(0,0)$**, then $(|X_{n+1}-X_n|,X_n)=(0,0)$;

**if $(X_{n+1},X_n)=(0,1)$**, then $(|X_{n+1}-X_n|,X_n)=(1,1)$;

**if $(X_{n+1},X_n)=(1,0)$**, then $(|X_{n+1}-X_n|,X_n)=(1,0)$;

**if $(X_{n+1},X_n)=(1,1)$**, then $(|X_{n+1}-X_n|,X_n)=(0,1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I have bad time with Markov chains. I can't understand what do you mean,  can you simplify the idea more!

Comment: The argument is a bijection argument. Let $f$ be a bijection:
$$
\{x=y\}=\{f(x)=f(y)\}
$$